# How to start with fullcalendar-rails gem in Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fullcalendar

I've followed instruction from https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails#installation for installation.
At the end I've added `<div id="calendar"></div>` to the view. But nothing happened - view is empty. Any ideas how to start with empty calendar (how to display it) in rails app?

Here are my files:
index.html.erb:

```
    <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-md-12'>
    <p><h4>Hello, <%= current_user.name %></h4></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .

//=require moment
//=require fullcalendar


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullcalendar({
    })
});
```

and in application.scss I've added only:

```
*= require fullcalendar
```

Comment: you might want to look [at this bug report](https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails/issues/64)

Comment: show us your files

Comment: @tsayen good catch! You may want to write this as an answer, specifically vital-edu's comment about what's needed in app/assets/javascripts/application.js

Comment: I've implemented what vital-edu said and it does not work still. @MarcosR.Guevara - files added above.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44021841/1648019, that is correct.
If you are using application.scss, you should use `@import 'fullcalendar'` instead of `*= require fullcalendar`

Answer (score 1):

And here goes the answer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({})
});
```

full**C**alendar, not full**c**alendar.

Maybe there was a change in the lib in the meantime.